# length of a path that passes through at least one vertex of each (elementary) circuit of a strong connected directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let $G$ be strongly connected directed graph with vertex set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. A circuit $i_0=i, i_1, \ldots, i_n=i$  is  elementary if path $ i_1, \ldots, i_{n-1}$ is a path in which
no vertex appears more than once.

In a paper, author claims that if  the length of any elementary circuit of $G$ is larger than or equal to 2, then there is a set $S=\{i_1,_2,\ldots, i_m\}\subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots n\}$ with  $m\leq [\frac{n}{2}]+1$ such that any elementary circuit of $G$ contains at least one vertex that belongs to $S$.

I do not know proof of it. Can you please help me to know it?

Indeed proof of the following lemme is not clear for me.

Lemma. Let  $G$ be strongly connected directed graph with vertex set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ and   the length of any elementary circuit of $G$ is larger than or equal to 2. If $i,j\in\{1, \ldots n\}$, then  there exists a (possibly empty) path $P_{ij}$ from $j$ to $i$ in $G$ that passes through at least one vertex of each (elementary) circuit of $G$ and that
has a length that is less than or equal to $\frac{n^2-1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the shortest elementary circuit allowed is a three-vertex circuit, then the claim is false (and very far from true).

Consider a random tournament: for each pair $\{i,j\}$, flip a coin to determine whether $G$ will have the directed edge $i \to j$ or $j \to i$. Then:

- With high probability, $G$ is strongly connected. For any set of vertices $S$, the probability is $2^{-|S| \cdot (n-|S|)}$ that all edges between $S$ and $V-S$ are oriented out of $S$, so the probability that $G$ is *not* strongly connected is at most $$\sum_{1 < |S| < n} 2^{-|S| \cdot (n-|S|)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom nk 2^{-k(n-k)} \le \binom n1 2^{1-n} + \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} \binom nk 2^{-2(n-2)} +\binom n{n-1}2^{1-n} \le \frac{4n+16}{2^n}$$ which decays very quickly with $n$.
- With high probability, $G$ has no transitive subtournament of size $t = 2\log_2 n+2$ (or larger). The expected number of such tournaments is $$\binom nt \cdot t! \cdot 2^{-t(t-1)/2} \le n^t 2^{-t(t-1)/2} = 2^{t(t-2)/2} \cdot 2^{-t(t-1)/2} = 2^{-t/2} = \frac1{2n}.$$

In particular, we can choose $G$ to satisfy both properties (assuming $\frac{4n+16}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2n}<1$, which happens when $n\ge 6$).

For any set $S$ of fewer than $n-t$ vertices, the complement of $S$ will not form a transitive tournament, and therefore there will be a cycle, none of whose vertices are in $S$. So when $n$ is large, you can't get away with a set $S$ of size $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor + 1$: you need a set $S$ of size almost $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding something in your notation but I think the result you require is false:-

Consider a graph with, say, $6$ vertices such that each pair of vertices is joined in each direction. Then, for any pair of vertices $i,j$, there is an elementary circuit $iji$.

Therefore $S$ has to include at least one of every pair of vertices and so $|S|\ge 5$.

Comment: I think, though I'm not sure, that the length of the elementary circuit $iji$ should be $1$ and so the hypotheses of the lemma are not satisfied. (Effectively, asking for all elementary circuits to be length $2$ or greater would mean forbidding edges $ij$ and $ji$ from existing at the same time.)

Comment: Right. I was assuming that the length condition simply prohibited loops. If the OP confirms this is the definition he is using I'll delete this post. It does seem odd though to use length  not meaning the number of edges and it also seems unusual to allow paths to repeat vertices.

Comment: @S.Dolan, Thanks, In its proof,  Author put $S=\{i_1=j,  i_2, \ldots, i\_m\}$ with $m\leq \frac{n+1}{2}$  such that any elementary circuit of G contains at least one vertex that belongs to S . Take path $P_k$  form $i_k$ to $i_{k+1}$ for $1\leq k<m$.

Comment: clearly  length of $P_k$ is atmost $n-1$. Also let $P_m$ be a path from $i_m$ to $i$. Then $P_{ij}:=P_1P_2\ldots P_m$ is a path from $j$ to $i$ and it passes through at least one vertex of each (elementary) circuit of G and that has a length that is less than or equal to $m(n-1)\leq \frac{n+1}{2}(n-1)=\frac{n^2-1}{2}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov       But it is not clear for me existence of $S$ with this property that every elementary circuit contains atleast one vertex that belongs to $S$. Please help me to know it.

Comment: Does the author  make this claim as if it is obvious or does it follow some other result?